# The type attribute ID in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

Is there any way to specify the length of the attribute ID. I can do :

```
<!ATTLIST Film ip ID #REQUIRED>
```

But i not specify length ID or do somehow equivalent.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible in DTD. Consider [XSD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/).

Comment: I need for a work for university and this is a specification.

Comment: Your needs do not change the validity of Kirill's answer.

Comment: Very true, so I put the stick, one does not remove the other, I do not disregard the professionalism of those who help me, because this forum is a mine of information and support for every programmer who is in doubt.
Still I was trying to do but I did not miss,